# What does it mean to have only lag significance on certain multiples of 7

Tags: time-series, seasonality, lags, acf-pacf, covid-19

I have a dataset named covid and after creating an acf graph of it , it looks something like this[image: image of ar]

Why is it that it is only showing lag significance on lags which are multiples of 7 only , dose it mean it has some kind seasonal trend ?

Comment: days of a week? I know some countries don't test or don't report tests on weekends and then put it all on Monday, so Mondays are inflated, can it be it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can be confident that this is a day of the week effect.

In many places, and perhaps most, what is reported or done or happens as far as Covid is concerned varies with day of the week. This seems to apply, although for different reasons, to reports of cases, reports of deaths, and reports of vaccinations. In many countries for different reasons, Fridays, Saturdays and Sundays can all be different. This is likely to be well known for whatever place you are looking at.

For this reason, and others, it is common to average numbers over 7-day windows in reporting as a way to smooth out artefacts.

What is true generally in time series analysis is that a strong and surprising pattern in autocorrelation functions should lead to attempts to cross-check against the original data, although you may need to do other analyses first. Here, some kind of moving average or median could be followed by plotting departures from that average against time or more explicitly day of week.

(Sometimes a strong pattern is no surprise, as when an autocorrelation function decays fairly quickly as a mark of lows and highs often being clustered, just as air temperatures from day to day reflect warmer or coller spells; when or one decays slowly because a series is dominated by trend that we have yet to set aside.)

Seasonality used to mean variations according to time of year. Its extension by some time series people to include time of month, time of week and time of day effects is both natural analytically and awkward linguistically, in my view, but that's a very little deal so long as usage is understood. What varies from field to field is whether seasonality is interesting or important or just irrelevant or irritating.

Comment: Thank you so much nick
but just one extra doubt i had about timeseries is that can you tell me what method is more efficient to use if my errors are increasing as time increases

Comment: That is really an entirely new and different and very wide question. Without being a time series expert at all I imagine that many threads here address it. Keywords may include heteroscedastic or heteroscedasticity. Working with logarithms would be my first device.